# Spring MongoDB inserting unwanted objects

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I haven't been able to find a single web page or other post about this issue. Hence, I'm here posting.

Within the documents I am storing to my mongodb, I have these things showing up:

```
"itemModifiers" : [
  {
    "val$implicitModifierString" : "16% increased Spell Damage",
    "modifierName" : "16% increased Spell Damage"
  }
]
```

The `val$implicitModifierString` is actually a variable from within my Java code, which was not set to the `ItemModifiers.class` instance. Basically, when I set a variable in my classes which I am storing to MongoDb, any variable or Object that I use to set that variable is also getting stored to the database (or at least that is what it looks like to me!).

Here is some sample code of what the process looks like (if you hate maps, sorry; not really relevant here.):

```
public ItemModifier deriveModifier(final String modifier) {
    for (Pattern outerKey : tierMap.keySet()) {
      if (outerKey.matcher(modifier).matches()) {
        HashMap<Pattern, ItemModifierTier> innerMap = tierMap.get(outerKey);
        for (Pattern innerKey : innerMap.keySet()) {
          if (innerKey.matcher(modifier).matches()) {
            Matcher innerMatcher = innerKey.matcher(modifier);
            Double[] tierValues = new Double[innerMatcher.groupCount()];
            innerMatcher.find();
            for (int i = 1; i <= innerMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
              tierValues[i - 1] = Double.valueOf(innerMatcher.group(i));
            }
            return new ItemModifier() {{
              setModifierName(modifier);
              setModifierTerm(termMap.get(outerKey.pattern()));
              setModifierTier(innerMap.get(innerKey));
              setModifierType(itemModifierType);
              setModifierValues(tierValues);
            }};
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And here is the ItemModifier class (intentionally indexed every field because they are all queryable via a service; I have not yet created composite indexes but plan to once the issue at hand is sorted):

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "modifierName",
  "modifierTerm",
  "modifierType",
  "modifierTier",
  "modifierValues",
  "modifierAverage"
})
public class ItemModifier {

  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierName")
  private String modifierName;
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierTerm")
  private String modifierTerm;
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierType")
  private ItemModifierType modifierType;
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierTier")
  private ItemModifierTier modifierTier;
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierValues")
  private Double[] modifierValues;
  @Indexed
  @JsonProperty("modifierAverage")
  private Double modifierAverage;

  public ItemModifier() {
  }

  public String getModifierName() {
    return modifierName;
  }

  public void setModifierName(String modifierName) {
    this.modifierName = modifierName;
  }
//... the other getters/setters
}
```

This `ItemModifiers.class` is held within an `ItemDocument.class` and is stored to the mongo database simply by invoking `mongoOperations.insert(itemDocumentInstance);`.

In case it matters, this is my mongoConfig.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017"/>
  <mongo:db-factory dbname="public-stash-api"/>

  <bean id="mappingContext"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>

  <bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey">
      <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext"/>
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does any of the class having Map as a property ? especially composite objects of ItemModifier

Comment: Member variables are all Enum, Double[], Double, or String. No maps.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Jackson with MongoDB. The fact that MongoDB uses documents does not mean it is using Jackson. MongoDB stores document in BSON (Binary JSON) format but you can't customize the way your documents are stored by using Jackson annotations.

There are Spring Data MongoDB annotations (like `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field`) for that very purpose. You actually used one of them in your code (`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed`).

Comment: That's a good point. I've corrected that (changed JsonProoerty ("...") to Field ("....")) but the result hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is the culprit:

```
return new ItemModifier() {{
  setModifierName(modifier);
  setModifierTerm(termMap.get(outerKey.pattern()));
  setModifierTier(innerMap.get(innerKey));
  setModifierType(itemModifierType);
  setModifierValues(tierValues);
}};
```

The static instantiation is what caused the weird `val$inputVariables` to persist into the Mongo Documents via Spring.